# I have created a css drop menu and the 'hover' will not work in certain versions of Internet Explorer, but will in other platforms

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu

I have a css drop menu that works in all browsers except IE10...works in IE11 and Chrome, etc. I am using Homestead Intuit as the provider.
 How can I get the drop down menu to work in IE10 and all versions?

My problem is the hover drop downs work fine in chrome, IE11, but not in IE10. I need the menu to work across all browsers and versions. 
One forum I read mentioned that IE doesn't recognize the hover and you have to use java to get around that, but I am not familiar with java or much html coding beyond the basics.
And by not working, I mean that in IE 10, there are no drop downs from the menu at all and the only link that is clickable is the 'Home' and that is because it is not connected to a hover function.

Here is the link to the page...  www.LovingHands.net/basketball.html

Here is the head code...

```
<head>    
  <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
    }    
    img {
        border-width: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
    }    
    .dfltc {
        font-family: Impact;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
    }    
    #Oobj21761 {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 10px;
        z-index: 1;
        text-align: left;
        left: 8.90em;
        top: 13.40em;
        width: 71.30em;
        height: 4.40em;
    }    
    #Oobj21763 {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 10px;
        z-index: 2;
        text-align: left;
        left: 9.10em;
        top: 20.10em;
        width: 71.10em;
        height: 4.60em;
    }    
    /*---- CROSS BROWSER DROPDOWN MENU ----*/    
    ul#nav {
        margin: 0 -200 0 -145px;
    }    
    ul.drop a {
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }    
    ul.drop, ul.drop li, ul.drop ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        background: #470001;
        color: #fff;
    }    
    ul.drop {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 597;
        float: left;
    }    
        ul.drop li {
            float: left;
            line-height: 1.3em;
            vertical-align: middle;
            zoom: 1;
            padding: 1px 30px;
        }    
            ul.drop li.hover, ul.drop li:hover {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 599;
                cursor: default;
                font-size:;
                background: #000000;
            }    
        ul.drop ul {
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 598;
            width: 224px;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            border: 1px solid #470001;
        }    
            ul.drop ul li {
                float: none;
            }    
            ul.drop ul ul {
                top: -2px;
                left: 100%;
            }    
        ul.drop li:hover > ul {
            visibility: visible;
        }    
    -->
</style>
```

Here is the css menu...

```
<div id="Oobj21761">
<div id="Gcode17050" class="dfltc">    
    <ul id="nav" class="drop">    
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>    
        <li>
            About
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/meetourstaff.html">Meet Our Staff</a></li>
                <li>
                    Endorsements
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/endorsementsGOVT.html">Official / Legal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/endorsementsPastors.html">Pastors / Ministers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/endorsementsMISC.html">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/support.html">Our Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="/facts.html">F.A.Q.</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li>
            Admission
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/admissioninfo.html">Admission Info</a></li>
                <li>
                    Endorsements
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/endorsementsGOVT.html">Official / Legal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/endorsementsPastors.html">Pastors / Ministers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/endorsementsMISC.html">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li>
            Testimonies
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Videos.html">Individual</a></li>
                <li><a href="/FullService.html">Full Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Scheduleing-Request.html">Schedule Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Sermons.html">Sermons</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li>
            Locations
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Bradenton-Palmetto.html">Bradenton/Palmetto</a></li>
                <li><a href="/DadeCity.html">Dade City, FL</a></li>
                <li><a href="/India.html">India</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Miami.html">Miami, FL</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Indiana.html">Jamestown, IN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li>
            Programs
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Events.html">Events & Fundraiers</a></li>
                <li><a href="/India.html">Loving Hands India</a></li>
                <li><a href="/JuggaloOutreach.html">Juggalo Outreach</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
        <li>
            Contact
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/prayerrequest.html">Prayer Requests</a></li>
                <li><a href="/joinourmailinglist.html">Join Mailing List</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Scheduleing-Request.html">Schedule Service</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `<doctype>` issue? ...and what's with that IE5 meta thing?

Comment: I had already removed the IE5, that was a fix someone suggested, but didn't work.  Does the DOCTYPE work in the head section of the code?  I am using Homestead Sitebuilder, very old WYSIWYG editor, so I don't think I can enter any code above the Head section.

Comment: First of all, please fix your HTML errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lovinghands.net%2Fbasketball.html